# Track mouse position to create onfling gesture in javascript

Tags: javascript, android, mouseevent, onfling

What type of event can I use to track the mouse to create an onfling gesture in javascript?I have thought to something but nothing...

Answer (score 0):

to track the mouse 
use mousemove event